# How to get current item in ItemTemplate in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, itemtemplate

I set template for item `ListView` and assign list items

```
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomVeggieCell));  
listView.ItemsSource = posts;
```

How to get `currentItem` element in `CustomVeggieCell`:

CustomVeggieCell.class:

```
    public class CustomVeggieCell : ViewCell
   {
          public CustomVeggieCell(){
        // for example int count = currentItem.Images.Count;
        var postImage = new Image
        {
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        postImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Images[0]"));
        var postImage = new Image
        {
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        postImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Images[1]"));
        }
    }
```

I want to get amount of `Images` in `ItemTemplate`.  `Images` is simply a list of strings.

p.s. All value in `ItemTemplate` I get by binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current item in an `ItemTemplate` you only need to reference the `CustomVeggieCell`'s `BindContext` like so:

```
string imageString = (string)BindingContext; //Instead of string, you would put what ever type of object is in your 'posts' collection
```

Having said that, your code does not completely make sense to me. If your `CustomVeggieCell` is in a `ListView`, it should not need to access a list of items by hardcoding the index of the item like you have here:

```
new Binding("Images[1]")
```

The `ListView` should basically do a `foreach` through all of the items for you. Unless `posts` contains a property which is `List<string>`.

Edit: Now that I have a better understanding of the issue. You may be able to create a new bindable property on your `ViewCell` and specify a method in the OnPropertyChanged param to add the images to a layout and then add the layout to your `ViewCell`. I have never tried anything like this so be that this all might not work at all.

Something like:

```
public class CustomVeggieCell : ViewCell
{
    public List<ImageSource> Images {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImagesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImagesProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Images", typeof(List<ImageSource>), typeof(CustomVeggieCell), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, ImageCollectionChanged);

    private StackLayout _rootStack;

    public InputFieldContentView() {
        _rootStack = new StackLayout {
            Children = //Some other controls here if needed
        };

        View = _rootStack;
    }

    private static void ImageCollectionChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue) {
        List<ImageSource> imageCollection = (List<ImageSource>)newValue;

        foreach(ImageSource imageSource in imageCollection) {
            (CustomVeggieCell)bindable)._rootStack.Children.Add(new Image { Source = imageSource });
        }
    }
}
```

Or something like that. Then you would bind your `posts.Images` to your new bindable property. Again I wrote that code just now in the text box and have not tested anything like that before, but let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for response. But BindingContext always is null, when I tried to get  var allModel = BindingContext as  WallPostViewModel;  or var images = (IList<string>)BindingContext; In any cases value and BindingContext are null...

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy The `CustomVeggieCell.BindingContext` will stay `null` until the `ListView` fills up with `CustomVeggieCell`s and the data is shown on the screen. Try to explain what you are trying to do with `CustomVeggieCell.BindingContext` and maybe we can help you further.

Comment: I want to get images from currentItem because each post has different amount photos and that's why I want to display different amount of photos for currentItem using different layouts.

Comment: I want to get bindable property value in constructor in viewcell-class and use this value in some condition in this constructor. On depending condition I want display different layouts( for 1, 2 ,3 images)

Answer (score 0):

1. In the constructor of `CustomVeggieCell` place minimum code. E.g.

   ```
   content = new StackLayout(); 
   View = content;
   ```

   (assuming you've declared "private StackLayout content" in the fields of `CustomVeggieCell`)
2. In this class, override `OnBindingContextChanged`. At this time, `this.BindingContext` contains the current item. You can now adapt the content of the base stackLayout according to the data just inserting in the `ListView`.